# Why is a dog (the Grim) the "worst omen" of death?

Tags: harry-potter

Why would the wizards be so terrified of a spectre of a dog?

Spectres are fairly common in the wizrading world, so why does the Grim terrify them so? Why is it special? Is the Grim alike the mythical [Barghest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barghest), or is it a real, existing threat in the wizarding world?

> "My dear," Professor Trelawney's huge eyes opened dramatically, "you have the Grim."
>
> "The what?" said Harry. He could tell that he wasn't the only one who didn't understand; Dean Thomas shrugged at him and Lavender Brown looked puzzled, **but nearly everybody else clapped their hands to their mouths in horror.**
>
> "The Grim, my dear, the Grim!" cried Professor Trelawney, who looked shocked that Harry hadn't understood. "The giant, spectral dog that haunts churchyards! My dear boy, it is an omen — the worst omen — of death!"

Comment: I don't recall a canon source explaining the origins of the Grim or why is it a dog. It is probably related to the Black dog legend, which is from the british folkore: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_dog_(ghost)

Comment: A " giant, spectral dog" reminds me of the Baskerville Hound from Sherlock Holmes stories. It may be something from British folklore

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It isn’t clear if the Grim is a real creature.

It’s never made clear whether the Grim is actually a real creature or not. Ron says his Uncle Bilius saw one and died, and also that most wizards are terrified of them. However, as Hermione says, that doesn’t necessarily mean the Grim is real - wizards may have simply misattributed characteristics to normal black dogs and created a self-fulfilling prophecy by scaring themselves to death.

> “Hermione, if Harry’s seen a Grim, that’s – that’s bad,’ he said. ‘My – my Uncle Bilius saw one and – and he died twenty-four hours later!’
>
> ‘Coincidence,’ said Hermione airily, pouring herself some pumpkin juice.
>
> ‘You don’t know what you’re talking about!’ said Ron, starting to get angry. ‘Grims scare the living daylights out of most wizards!’
>
> ‘There you are, then,’ said Hermione in a superior tone. ‘They see the Grim and die of fright. The Grim’s not an omen, it’s the cause of death! And Harry’s still with us because he’s not stupid enough to see one and think, right, well, I’d better pop my clogs then!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 6 (Talons and Tea Leaves)*</sup></sub>

The existence of the Grim is never explicitly stated to be only a legend, either, so it’s also possible that the Grim does exist, and Harry just didn’t encounter a real one.

## It’s likely based on church grims in legend.

Trelawney explains to her Divination class that the Grim is a giant spectral dog that haunts churchyards, which is similar to the British legends of church grims.

> “The Grim, my dear, the Grim!’ cried Professor Trelawney, who looked shocked that Harry hadn’t understood. ‘The giant, spectral dog that haunts churchyards! My dear boy, it is an omen – the worst omen – of death!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 6 (Talons and Tea Leaves)*</sup></sub>

Though she’s never yet said where she specifically got the idea for the Grim from, she has said that generally she tried to use British mythology and folklore as the basis for the story.

> In any case, vampires are a tradition of Eastern Europe, and in general I tried to draw from British mythology and folklore when creating adversaries for Harry. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Vampires (Pottermore)](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/vampires)*</sup></sub>

In British mythology, as described in a book on locally used vocabulary published in 1876, a church-grim is a ghost created by burying a creature alive in the church’s wall. It warned of approaching death, and one of the common animals it could be was a dog.

> **Grim,** a ghost. A skeleton. ‘A *grim’s* head,’ a death’s head. Evidently a part of ‘Church-*grim,*’ a term we have only once heard used in this quarter, though that may tend to countenance the notion of its former-day currency, especially as it stands associated with our ‘Barguest.’ On this point we learn, that in certain countries, a custom prevailed with those engaged in the building of a church, to take the first living creature which crossed their path on a day approaching its completion, and build it alive in the wall. Thus it became the haunting inhabitant of the church, and it was the office of this sprite to give warning of approaching death. Accordingly, different animal forms pertained to the several *kirke-grims* of a district, as we hear of Barguests in the shape of a mastiff, a pig, a dog, a calf. Further, as kindly communicated by the Rev. J. C. Atkinson, author of the Cleveland Glossary, the Church - grim at times, was visible to the priest while officiating at the grave, and to no one else. The priest was wont to cast his eyes towards the window of the church-tower where the apparition sat, and he could then tell by the creature’s aspect whether the departed was saved or lost. See *Barguest, Scriker*. 
> <sub><sup>*[- A Glossary of Words Used in the Neighbourhood of Whitby (by Francis Kildale Robinson, published 1876)](https://books.google.com/books?id=fNCZ2PG70sQC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=church%20grim&source=bl&ots=AlQsXpO_t4&sig=ACfU3U2p78UAyDmMKOlgkxDg3QcXfOQEDg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)*</sup></sub>

Barguests, another British folktale mentioned in the entry for church grims as a further reference, are also animal apparitions that are commonly dogs and are omens of death. However, they’re not said to have any connection to churchyards, which both the church grim of British mythology and the Grim in Harry Potter do, so the church grim is more likely to be the basis for what’s said in Harry Potter.

> **Barguests,** *or* **Boh-ghosts,** s. pl. terrifying apparitions, taking shape human or animal. See *Boh-ghost,* which is, perhaps, a more general term, and the two words may be distinct. Some say, *Barguest* signifies Castle-specter (most ancestral buildings having their haunting inhabitants), from A.S. *burh* a fortified place, and *gast*, a ghost; others consider it to be *bier-ghost* as being a harbinger of death, from A.S. *bere*, a bier; but we are rightly told to be cautious about etymologies. According to the popular version, the *barguest,* whether dog or demon, glares with large eyes, ‘like burning coals;’ and Grose informs us (evidently by guess), that they haunt the streets and lanes at nights, and take their stand at gates or styles, which, in Yorkshire, he adds, are called *bars!* Be this as it may, the *bar-guest,* like the *church-Grim,* is a harbinger of death to those who happen to hear its shrieks in the night; for they are not audible except to people ‘whose times have nearly come.’ So and so will die soon, ‘for last night he heard the *barguest.*’ See *Grim.* 
> <sub><sup>*[- A Glossary of Words Used in the Neighbourhood of Whitby (by Francis Kildale Robinson, published 1876)](https://books.google.com/books?id=fNCZ2PG70sQC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=church%20grim&source=bl&ots=AlQsXpO_t4&sig=ACfU3U2p78UAyDmMKOlgkxDg3QcXfOQEDg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, since JKR generally takes inspiration from British mythology, and the church grim and the Grim in Harry Potter are in their basic description effectively the same, it’s almost certain that she based the Grim in Harry Potter on the church grims of British mythology and folklore.

Comment: You may want to clarify who “she” is in the paragraph beginning with “though”. I assume you are referring to Rowling, but at that point in the post you haven’t mentioned her yet. Coming off the previous paragraph it makes it seem like you’re referring to Trelawney.

Comment: We only have it on Trelawney's word that it is **the worst** omen of death, and she's a bit of a drama queen.